# How to show form errors in django-bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using earle / django-bootstrap to show a form styled with twitter bootstrap. I want to be able to change the style and show the errors the user committed while filling the form (i.e. if he missed a required field)

I cannot find in the documentation on how to output errors. I am submitting the form using jquery.form.js and returning errors in an array in a dictionary, the problem is, the errors array returns empty, and even printing the errors array in the view shows it empty.

The code for the form:

```
class SomeForm(BootstrapForm):
    class Meta:
        layout = (
        Fieldset( "Form title:","first_field", "second_field", ),
    )

    first_field = forms.CharField(label=u'Some Text', max_length=50,    error_messages={'required':u'The error msg',},required=True,)
    second_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(label=Some Text', queryset=SomeClass.objects.all(), error_messages={'required':u'The error msg. ',}, required=True, )
```

And the code for the view:

```
@login_required
def new_case(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_case = form.save(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/casos/')
        else:
            response_dict = {'ok': False, 'msg': None, 'err': None,}
            err = {}
            caseErrors = {}
            caseErrors.update(form.errors)
            for field in caseErrors:
                caseErrors[field] = [unicode(error) for error in caseErrors[field]] 
            err['caso']=caseErrors   
            response_dict['msg'] = u'The fields are not valid.'
            response_dict['err'] = err
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        form = SomeForm()
        return render_to_response('casos/new_case.html', { 'form': form },    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Also the jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#agr_ncaso').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSubmit: before_submit,
        success: success
    });
});

function before_submit(formData, jqForm, options) {
    $('.error').removeClass('error');
    $('.alert-error').remove();
    return true; 
}

function success(json) {
    if (json.ok) {
        window.location = '/casos/';
    }
    else if (json.err) {            
        $('<div class="alert alert-error"><strong>Error inform </strong></div>').insertBefore('form')       
        for (campo in json.err) {
        $('#div_id_' + campo).addClass("error");
        }
        $('.alert').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else {
        alert(json.msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors of the form are inside err['casos'], not inside err. Have a great day

Comment: Thanks, I had copied the code from a previous project. Guess I changed something off.